# AND operator in @Profile annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have this configuration class in my Spring Boot appl. v1.5.3.RELEASE

```
@Configuration
@Profile("dev && cub")
@PropertySource("file:///${user.home}/.cub/application-dev.properties")
public class CubDevelopmentConfig {
..
}
```

and this property defined in my application.properties

```
spring.profiles.active=dev, cub
```

but the config class is not loaded

I also tried `@Profile("{dev && cub}")`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the array form of the `value()` method of the annotation to specify multiple values.
That is :
 `@Profile({"dev", "cub"})`

Nevertheless, this configuration don't mean that both "dev" and "cub" profiles are required.
The presence of at least one of them validates the condition.

To enable the configuration only if both profiles are present, Spring Boot didn't provide a solution out of the box so far.
From Spring Core 5.1 (Spring Boot 2.1 or more) you can at last use some expression in `@Profile`.  Beware that are not EL but limited expressions.

> A profile string may contain a simple profile name (for example **"p1"**)
>   or a profile expression. A profile expression allows for more
>   complicated profile logic to be expressed, for example **"p1 & p2"**. See
>   **Profiles.of(String...)** for more details about supported formats.

According to the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html), we could specify the presence of multiple profiles as condition :

```
@Profile("dev & cub")
```

The presence of one or another profile could be expressed more explicitly now :

```
@Profile("dev | cub")
```

And we could also rely on negation, for example  :

```
@Profile("dev & !cub")
```

Note that `&` and `|` cannot be mixed in a same expression without using parenthesis. So it should be used as :

```
@Profile("(dev & integ) | cub")
```

You can retrieve all rules concerning `Profile` expressions [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Profiles.html#of-java.lang.String...-).

As a general note, beware about union of profiles as activation rule because it may be caused by a bad design where we couple too much the "environments".